# Adding and Dragging images into a div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I'm new to jQuery, so i thought to ask here.

I'm looking for a script which generates a div, where users can select images from a list which will add the image to the div and makes them draggable. So users are able to "design" their own simple card.

Anyone knows how to name this? Or do you have a script like this?

Comment: Have you mad a start on your code?

Answer (score 1):

take a look to this [link](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)

it´s a start for you. in this link you have an example and you can check the source code of the javascript.

what you have to do is to change the code for your needs